# loadAudioFiles throws error

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I am using the following code snippet:

```
import AVFoundation


var ae:AVAudioEngine
var sampler:AVAudioUnitSampler
var mixer:AVAudioMixerNode

var midiNoteNumberFor:Dictionary<String,UInt8> = [
    "BD":48,
    "Snr":50,
    "Hat":52,
    "Hit":53,
    "VI":68,
    "V":67,
    "i":60,
    "III": 63
]
    let urls = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "wav", subdirectory: "wavs")

    ae = AVAudioEngine()
    mixer = ae.mainMixerNode
    sampler = AVAudioUnitSampler()

    ae.attach(sampler)
    ae.connect(sampler, to: mixer, format: sampler.outputFormat(forBus: 0))

    do {
        try sampler.loadAudioFiles(at: urls!)

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }


    do {
        try ae.start()

    } catch {
        print("Error info: \(error)")
    }


func play(snd:String){
    sampler.startNote(midiNoteNumberFor[snd]!, withVelocity: 127,onChannel: 0)

}
```

However, when I run the function `play(snd: "BD")`, it throws the following error:

> Error Domain=com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio Code=-10851 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={failed call=error}

which is coming from the first catch clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In build settings you need to add a file reference to the wavs directory.